# ImportError: No module named 'spiders'

Tags: python, scrapy

On the command line I'm executing the following simple attempt to invoke scrapy:

```
scrapy version
```

I get the following error:

```
$ scrapy version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 141, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 238, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 325, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 33, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 20, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 28, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 63, in walk_modules
    mod = import_module(path)
  File "/Users/nathanielford/virtualenvironments/crawler/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'spiders'
```

If I leave my project directory, the error no longer occurs:

```
$ scrapy version
Scrapy 1.2.2
```

What is causing the `ImportError: No module named 'spiders'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error was caused by my `settings.py` file, where the I had the following:

```
SPIDER_MODULES = ['spiders']
```

While it is in the default project provided by `scrapy`, I had moved that module. Values in that list need to be fully qualified module names: even trivial executions of `scrapy` will load the settings file, and thus try to import modules from your project. If it can find a settings file, it will need to be correct.

Comment: great catch, I would recommend mentioning this as an issue in the [repository](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues)