# "moduleNotFoundError" when sets scrapy as an app in django

Tags: python, django, scrapy

When I tried to start my scrapy demo with `scrapy crawl getCommodityInfo`, the error below occurred.

```
C:\Users\柘宇\PycharmProjects\GraduationProject\spiders\bin\JDSpider>scrapy crawl getCommodityInfo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anacaonda\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute())
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 141, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 238, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 325, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 45, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 23, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 32, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\柘宇\PycharmProjects\GraduationProject\spiders\bin\JDSpider\JDSpider\spiders\getCommodityInfo.py", line 12, in <module>
    from spiders.bin.JDSpider.JDSpider.items import JDCommodity
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spiders'
```

It seems that the spider cannot be found, but I don't know why it happened. My whole [project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjtqQ.png) is here. **GraduationProject** is the django project. **main** and **spiders** are the applications of django. The **bin** directory stores two demo scrapy projects. When I entered the JDSpider trying to run it, the error occurred. Could you help me fix it?

PS. My spider name:  `name = "getCommodityInfo"`

---

With the solution applied by *PS1212*, the scrapy demo could run. However the pycharm warns like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQlks.png). What happened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'spiders'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028605/importerror-no-module-named-spiders)

Comment: My scrapy version is 1.3.3. So the bug in the link is impossible in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because it it not recognizing you project module.

Try this:

```
 from JDSpider.items import JDCommodity
```

Comment: Thx, It works. However, why the codes after edited are warned by pycharm as "Unresolved reference 'JDSpider' "

Comment: Not sure. Can you update your question with this error?